# Usage of tf.space_to_batch_nd() and tf.batch_to_space_nd()

Tags: tensorflow

I am implementing OCR with RNN on top of CNN features. And I can not understand mechanics of tf.space_to_batch_nd() and tf.batch_to_space_nd(). 
I need to apply fully connected layer on each time (1-st dim) slice of input layer to reduce tensor rank from 4 to 3 
I have working implementation of this via tf.reshape().
Input tensor shape is [1, 84, 7, 128], output should be [1, 84, 128]
My current implementation is:

```
with tf.variable_scope('dim_redux') as scope:
    conv_out_shape = tf.shape(net)
    print("Conv out:", str(net))    
    w_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 128, 128])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([128])
    conv_layer_flat = tf.reshape(net, [-1, 7 * 127])
    features = tf.matmul(conv_layer_flat, w_fc1) + b_fc1
    features = lrelu(h_bn3)
    features = tf.reshape(features, [batch_size, int(84), CONV_FC_OUTPUT])
```

And with tf.space_to_batch_nd() and tf.batch_to_space_nd():

```
    with tf.variable_scope('dim_redux') as scope:
        net = tf.space_to_batch_nd(net, block_shape=[84, 1], paddings=[[0, 0], [0, 0]])
        print(net)
        net = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(net)
        net = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(net, CONV_FC_OUTPUT, biases_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
        net = lrelu(net)
        print(net)
        net = tf.batch_to_space_nd(net, block_shape=[84, 128], crops=[[0, 0], [0, 0]])
        features = net
```

It seems that block shapes should be [1, 7], but only with this values [84, 1] tf.space_to_batch_nd() return tensor with correct shapes [84, 1, 7, 128].
With current params i hame following error:

```
File "/Users/akislinskiy/tag_price_ocr/ocr.py", line 336, in convolutional_layers
    net = tf.batch_to_space_nd(net, block_shape=[84, 128], crops=[[0, 0], [0, 0]])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 318, in batch_to_space_nd
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2632, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1911, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1861, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 595, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    require_shape_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 659, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Shape must be at least rank 3 but is rank 2 for 'convolutions/dim_redux/BatchToSpaceND' (op: 'BatchToSpaceND') with input shapes: [84,128], [2], [2,2].
```

Comment: Bump
Tensorflowers, I need your help